# Android: sqlite returning information from all rows containing a similar value in one row

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to have the user select a value, then search my database for that value, and return information from all rows containing that value.

I tried the following, but I am not sure how to return the results correctly to the other activity to be viewed by the user.

```
Cursor c = ourDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM FavoriteTable WHERE " + KEY_FAVNAME + " = '" + favoriteWorkoutName + "'", null);
```

I also tried this, where the int row is specifying the KEY_ROW I want to grab data from when querying.  For example, the user enters the name of a favorite workout, it then searches the database for all rows containing that name, and then returns KEY_ROWS 1, 2, and 3 (which correspond to Exercise, Reps, etc).  However, this only returns one row value from one row.

```
int row = 1;

    Cursor c = ourDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM FavoriteTable WHERE " + KEY_FAVNAME + " = '" + favoriteWorkoutName + "'", null);

    do{c.moveToNext();
    String data = c.getString(row);
    return data;
    }while (row <= 3);
```

Any suggestions?

****EDIT:

I had already had something in my activity like that.  Here is what I have there.  However, I am getting an error, and it asks me to either "Change type of listCursor to Cursor", which it already is...or to "Change return type of 'GetFavoriteData' to Cursor", which is also already is.

Also, when I do get that to not have an error, I'm not sure how to use that returned data and insert it into my TextView.  It will not allow me to setText(listCursor).

I ideally need to get the information from each returned row as a separate String so that I can display them the way I need to in TextViews.

In my Activity:

```
String favoriteWorkoutName = cfdName.getText().toString();

                ExerciseDatabase choosefavorite = new ExerciseDatabase(WorkMeOutActivity.this);
                try {
                    choosefavorite.open();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Cursor listCursor = choosefavorite.GetFavoriteData(favoriteWorkoutName);    


                choosefavorite.close();
```

in my DBHelper class:

```
public Cursor GetFavoriteData(String favoriteWorkoutName){

    return ourDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM FavoriteTable WHERE " + KEY_FAVNAME + " = '" + favoriteWorkoutName + "'", null);


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you misunderstood the [getString()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getString%28int%29) method. Have a look:

```
public abstract String getString (int columnIndex)
Since: API Level 1
```

### Returns the value of the requested column as a String.

```
The result and whether this method throws an exception when the column value is null or the column type is not a string type is implementation-defined.
Parameters
columnIndex     the zero-based index of the target column.
Returns

    the value of that column as a String.
```

---

So, if you pass 1,2 or 3 inside with c.getString(row) it only gives you value of only one column(with index 1,2 or 3) from a specific row.

---

You can use `c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(column_name))` if you are not sure about index of a column and want to get it from it's name.

---

Now I think you want to retrieve value of some columns(say first 3 column value of a row) from first few matching rows(like 3 rows) and use them if so use:

```
Cursor c = ourDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM FavoriteTable WHERE " + KEY_FAVNAME + " = '" + favoriteWorkoutName + "'", null);

String fcv="";
String scv="";
String tcv="";


if(c.getCount() == 0)
                    {
                     //no data found
                    }
                    else  {
                        int i=0;
                      c.moveToFirst();
                        do {


                              fcv  = fcv + c.getString(0)); //or use  fcv  = fcv + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(name of first column)));
                              scv  = fcv + c.getString(1)); 
                              tcv  = fcv + c.getString(2));   
                              i++;
                          } while (c.moveToNext() && i<3);              

                  c.close();
```

---

Use the value of the strings as you like according to your need :)

Comment: Ok...I tried this.  First - how do I return all of those strings to my activity?  When using the return statement, it only lets me return one (ex return fcv;)...if I try to return the others I get an error.  Also, I tried only returning the String fcv, and then set my TextView to that string, and nothing comes up.  Not sure what I am doing wrong...

Comment: Use this code in your activity on the cursor listCursor ( I mean use listCursor in place of c ) so that you don't need returning multiple(a function can return on value only) strings as the cursor already have them) Just assing those values to global variables to use them for TextView. And check you database  and query by tracing/logging according to value to be sure you are actually getting value.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear...

If you are trying to search all your different columns for that value your query should look more like this:

```
Cursor c = ourDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM FavoriteTable WHERE " + KEY_FAVNAME + 
    " LIKE '" + favoriteWorkoutName + "' OR " + COLUMN2 + " LIKE '" + favoriteWorkoutName + 
    "' OR " + COLUMN3 + " LIKE '" + favoriteWorkoutName + "'", null);
```

That will search columns KEY_FAVNAME, COLUMN2 and COLUMN3 and return any rows that contain favoriteWorkoutName's contents.

If you want only those from the specific column, what you first posted is correct.

**EDIT**

After re-reading, I'm getting a different idea of what your issue is.

You should call for the cursor in the activity in which you are going to use it.  The normal method is to define a DB helper class that creates the db and contains all functions related to it (adding, deleting, updating info, getting cursors, etc).  Then you instantiate that class and use it's methods to work with the db.

An example would be (used in the activity where you want to access the data):

```
mDbHelper = new WorkoutDB(getActivity());  // instantiate your dbhelper class
mDbHelper.open();                          // use the dbhelper open method to open the db
Cursor listCursor = mDbHelper.fetchFavoriteWorkout(favoriteWorkoutName);  // use the fetchFavoriteWorkout method to get your cursor
```

Your dbhelper class would contain a method (among many others) something like this:

```
public Cursor fetchFavoriteWorkout(String favoriteWorkoutName){
    return ourDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM FavoriteTable WHERE " + KEY_FAVNAME + " = '" +  favoriteWorkoutName + "'", null);                 
}
```

Comment: Ah, that's much clearer what you're looking for.  It looks like Imran Rana might have the solution you need.  If not let me know and I'll look at it some more.